# select an textbox from array of textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to select a textbox from array of textbox.
for this purpose  i tried th following method,but i am not getting any output

HTML code

```
<input type="text" id="total[]"/>
<input type="text" id="total[]"/>
<input type="text" id="total[]"/>
```

jquery

```
$i=0;
for($i = 0;$i < total.length;$i++;)
{
 $("#total\\[$i\\]").val($i);   
}
```

the above code does not displays anything.

Please help me to solve the problem

Edit

i have updated my demo,there

```
textbox at pos(0,2) total of(0,0) and (0,1) should come
textbox at pos(1,2) total of(1,0) and (1,1) should come
and
textbox at pos(2,0) total of(0,0) and (1,0) should come
textbox at pos(2,1) total of(0,1) and (1,1) should come
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hEDA8/6/)

Comment: Something is wrong here. Is `id="total[]"` supposed to be `name="total[]"`?

Comment: id cannot be same to diffrent controls

Comment: an `id` must be an unique element, furthermore - use `name=field[]` for saving array values`

Comment: yes for first text box  id will be total[0] second text box id will be total[1].

Comment: It looks to me you're trying to implement Java into JavaScript - this wouldn't even run before the loop as `total` isn't even defined when calling `.length`, that and you initialise an variable twice, `$i = 0;` then in the loop, `$i = 0; $i < ..` and lastly the `{}` on new lines!

Comment: Somnath Kharat answer was working fine and same as oGeez. But i just want to know which one is best practice?

Answer (score 2):

To apply `input`s to an array for server side processing, you must use the `name` attribute. The `id` attribute needs to be unique document-wide. If you had this markup:

```
<input type="text" name="total[]"/>
<input type="text" name="total[]"/>
<input type="text" name="total[]"/>
```

You can achieve what you want by passing a function to the `val()` method:

```
$('input[name^=total]').val(function(i){
   return i;
});
```

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/hEDA8/4/)

Comment: your answer was working fine and same as Somnath Kharat. But i just want to know which one is best practice?

Comment: @krishna The main issue with your code is that you have multiple `id`s the same, that is a big no no. As for whose is better practice - well they don't do the same thing.

Comment: @Learning but i cant differentiate each textbox with your answer,right?

Comment: if you want to differentiate them then give id to each element too.

Comment: @krishna What exactly are you trying to do? It seems that what you actually want doesn't reflect what you've written in the question.

Answer (score 0):

when you assign same IDs to multiple controls, and when you try to fetch them using jQuery or javascript, you get only the first occurence of them.

you should give different Ids to your controls, and to fetch them all in one go, try selecting them using `tagName` or give a uinque class to them and then select

try this:

```
<input class='operate' type="text" id="input1"/>
<input class='operate' type="text" id="input2"/>
<input class='operate' type="text" id="input3"/>
```

and your jQuery code

```
   $('input[type=text]').each(function(index,elem){
         this.value = index;
   });
```

or

```
   $('input.operate').each(function(index,elem){
          this.value = index;
   });
```

Comment: Or `this.value = index` to avoid creating a collection and calling a method on it.

Comment: ohh,yes yes, absolutely

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("[id^='total']").each(function(){
   alert($(this).attr("id"));//You will get id of all textbox here
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HeANb/)

Answer (score 0):

give same class to each input then iterate on it as :

Javacript

```
var i=0;
$(".txtbox").each(function(){
$(this).val(i++);
});
```

Html

```
<input type="text" class="txtbox"/>
<input type="text" class="txtbox"/>
<input type="text" class="txtbox"/>
```

check the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hEDA8/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `name` attribute.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="total[]"/>
<input type="text" name="total[]"/>
<input type="text" name="total[]"/>
```

**JavaScript**

Use **[.eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)** to select.

```
var $textboxes = $('input[name="total[]"]')

var value1 = $textboxes.eq(0).val();
var value2 = $textboxes.eq(1).val();
```